# nested queries mongoose .find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I have an issue doing a nested query that matches a value to a unique key.

My Schema is as follows:

```
const AnalyticsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    requestsByStatusNew: Number,
    requestsByStatusNewIds: Schema.Types.Mixed,
})
```

Where requestsByStatusNewIds is of the form:

```
{
  UNIQUE_ID: 1,
  ANOTHER_UNIQUE_ID: 1
}
```

What I would like to do is find and return an object in my collection where a query matches one of the nested unique ids. Is this possible?

This is what I tried to do:

```
const query = {
    requestsByStatusNewIds: {
    }
};

query['requestsByStatusNewIds'][`${request._id}`] = 1;

Analytics.find(query, '_id').then((err, analytics) => {
  console.log(analytics);
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: looks like you need and `or` to find all the docs where id equals to `Unique/anotherUnique` ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey how is this done in mongoose? .find({ requestsByStatusNewIds: { $or : { UNIQUE_ID: 1 } } })?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an `or` condition here for`UNIQUE_ID` and `ANOTHER_UNIQUE_ID`

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [{
        "requestsByStatusNewIds.UNIQUE_ID": "ID"
    }, {
        "requestsByStatusNewIds.ANOTHER_UNIQUE_ID": "ID"
    }]
});
```